# _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type method cannot be converted

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
##GUI FILE
root = Tk()
root.title("Inventory Management")
root.geometry('1000x600')

def add_inventory():
    myInventory = product.Product()
    myInventory.setProductID(productID.get())
    myInventory.setProdName(productName.get())
    myInventory.addProduct()

productID = IntVar()
productName = StringVar()

prodIDentry = Entry(productframe, width=22, textvariable=productID)
prodNameentry = Entry(productframe, width=22, textvariable=productName)

btn_add = Button(productframe, text="Add", font="Verdana 10 bold", command = add_inventory)
```

```
##product file
class Product:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ProductID = ''
        self.ProdName = ''

    prodID = self.getProductID()
    prodname = self.getProdName()
    
    def getProductID(self):
        return self.ProductID
    def setProductID(self, value):
        self.ProductID = value

    def getProdName(self):
        return self.getProdName
    def setProdName(self, value):
        self.ProdName = value

    def addProduct(self):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        database='PHP',
        user='root',
        password=''
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    sql1 = "INSERT INTO product (ProductID, ProdName) VALUES (%s,%s)"
    val = (prodID, prodname)

    mycursor.execute(sql1, val)
    mydb.commit()
```

My program has a GUI which requires user input, then it will take the input and put it into the database on a button click. These are few of my variables to be inserted.
But it keeps returning:_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type method cannot be converted

Comment: What happens if you `print(val)` just before the execute?

Comment: @AKX hi sorry i just added more codes into my problem, do take a look please :/ i need help

Comment: Your code makes no sense. For one, there's now MySQL code in the class body, outside any function? There also is no `getProductID()` function anywhere in the code.

Comment: @AKX i just edited again, im so sorry i am not very familiar with how to show the problem... isit better for u to understand now?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. If you have a problematic segment that calls a `self.getProductID()` function, you should also include that function in the post, for one.

Comment: @AKX i missed it out, my bad !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the function

```
def getProdName(self):
    return self.getProdName
```

It returns itself (`getProdName`), not the product name variable.

The MySQL connector says

> MySQLInterfaceError: Python type method cannot be converted

since it can't convert a method (`getProdName`) to something MySQL could understand.

Change the `getProdName()` method to return `ProdName`:

```
def getProdName(self):
    return self.ProdName
```

(or get rid of it altogether; setters and getters aren't very popular in Python.)